# Creating a thumbnail of an image fails with TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to create a background object using the PIL module, but there is an error that I do not understand. The code:

```
from PIL import Image
class background():
    def __init__(self, width, height, value):
        img = Image.open('new.png')
        img_new = img.thumbnail(width, height)
        for x in range(width):
            for y in range(height):
                img_new.putpixel(x, y, value)
        img_new.show()

bg = background(200, 200, 1)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\filename.py", line 11, in <module>
    bg = background(200, 200, 1)
  File "...\filename.py", line 5, in __init__.py
    img_new = img.thumbnail(width, height)
  File "...\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2205, in thumbnail
    if x > size[0]:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

What does this mean?

**UPDATE:** 
Now the object is acting as I thought(I could give it any size I want to), however, assigning the color became difficult. Isn't the `value` parameter a tuple of RGB values(i.e (255, 150, 0)? So when i input this parameter it gives me an error. It only accepts 1 input. For example: It only accepts

```
bg = background(600, 400, (255))
```

or

`bg = background(800, 800, (0))`

But not

`bg = background(800, 800, (255, 255, 255))`
or any variations in the values.

The code:

```
from PIL import Image

class background():
    def __init__(self, width, height, value):
        img = Image.new('I', (width, height))
        for x in range(width):
            for y in range(height):
                img.putpixel((x, y), value)
        img.show()
```

The error:
`SystemError: <method 'putpixel' of 'ImagingCore' objects> returned NULL without setting an error`

Comment: Your error and title don't match.

Comment: A *more complete* stack trace would help.

Comment: `thumbnail` has a single size argument. It expects width and height passed as something like `(width, height)`.

Answer (score 2):

The [`Image.thumbnail()` method](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.thumbnail) expects a single `size` argument, which is a *tuple* of the width and height:

```
img.thumbnail((width, height))
```

Or, perhaps clearer:

```
size = (width, height)
img.thumbnail(size)
```

The method also takes a second argument, `resample`; you passed in `width` for the size and `height` for the `resample` argument. By passing in `width` as the size, you get your error. As the method tries to index the `width` value (expecting a tuple) the exception is thrown as an integer can't be indexed.

You have a similar error calling [`Image.putpixel()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.putpixel), the position is also a tuple:

```
img_new.putpixel((x, y), value)
```

Note that you really don't need to open an existing image. If you wanted to create an empty image of uniform colour, just use [`Image.new()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.new)

```
class background():
    def __init__(self, width, height, value):
        img_new = Image.new("I", (width, height), value)
        # ... do something with the new, uniformly coloured image.
```

You need to [pick an image mode](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes) here; given that your `value` is a single integer value  I picked `I`, in which pixels are represented by 32-bit signed integers. The above creates an image that is the right size and has all pixels set to `value`.